# How to swap two tuples inside a tuple?

Tags: python, matrix, tuples

The input is a tuple with multiple tuples, each one is a line in a matrix.
Ex:

```
m = ((1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0))

# (1 0 0 0)
# (0 0 1 0)
# (0 0 0 1)
# (0 1 0 0)
```

The idea is to swap the tuples that have a 0 in the diagonal by one that doesn't.

```
    for j in range(len(m)):
        if matriz[j][j] == 0:
            for k in range(len(m)):
                if m[k][j] != 0:
                    ?
```

The expected output after all the iterations would be this:

```
m = ((1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1))

# (1 0 0 0)
# (0 1 0 0)
# (0 0 1 0)
# (0 0 0 1)
```

In this example the 2nd and 3rd tuples swapped positions.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Tuples are immutable. You have to create a *new* tuple with the elements swapped; you can't modify the original tuple in-place.

Comment: if they're all going to be in that format, you could just sort the tuples based on the index of 1. You'd have to assign the result to a new tuple though because tuples are immutable.

Comment: They won't all be in that format. actually most of them will be different from one but I used 1's and 0's because it's easier to picture it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
m = tuple(sorted(m, reverse=True)) 
# ((1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1))
```

Comment: Will this work if I use other values instead of 1?

Comment: Ordered in that way: biggest first element, biggest second element, ... So if you use "identity matrix" like, it will work without any problem.

Comment: I'm not using an identity matrix tho. I just used 1's and 0's because it was easier to see.